# How to obtain the offset of a MASM local variable at assembly time

Tags: local, offset, masm

I want to obtain the offset into the stack frame of a MASM procedure's local variable at assembly time (not runtime, the LEA instruction isn't useful here). E.g., if the local variable is at RBP-8 at run time, I want to obtain the constant (-8) during assembly.

Is this possible?

OFFSET operator only works on global (static) variables. Every suggestion I've found on the internet talks about using LEA, which is not what I want.

```
someProc  proc
          local  a:byte, b:word, c:dword
           .
           .
           . someConst =  MagicOffset(a) ;Magically sets constant "someConst" to the offset of "a" (probably something like -8).

someProc  endp
```

Comment: The answer is no, not directly. Although this article explains a way to get the effect but it requires you manually creating STRUCTs that can be used to compute offsets at assemble time. This isn't likely what you would have hoped for, but it is probably about the closest you'd get. http://collaboration.cmc.ec.gc.ca/science/rpn/biblio/ddj/Website/articles/DDJ/1988/8809/8809d/8809d.htm#01a1_0013

Comment: Sounds like it might be an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Why is it that you need to get the offset of local variables/parameters on the stack like this? WHat problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Yup, I figured I'd have to do all the work myself (maintaining the offsets manually and giving up on the MASM local and parameters features).

The problem I am trying to solve is to write a macro that lets you declare lexically nested procedures in MASM (with access to intermediate variables via a display). Got about 400 lines into the macro before I discovered that I wouldn't be able to use something like "b textequ <[rbp-8]> as a reference to local variables. The problem is, you can't reuse "b" afterwards. Any reuse of "b" translates to the text. So I wanted to see if I could use locals.